# Debugging gulp task is very slow to hit first breakpoint

Tags: node.js, performance, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I have a gulp task I am debugging but to hit the first break point takes a really long time.

This is how I debug my task

```
node-debug gulp taskName
```

It brings up chrome and it takes about 30 seconds to hit my break point. I want to note that my gulp file and code I am trying to debug is very small and a very light weight.

Comment: Can you post your gulpfile?

Comment: I found the issue with my situation. The gulp file has globally defined requires that were adding to the load time. Once I removed them it loads in about 2 seconds.

Comment: Who ever created the file did not realize the debugging implications. I guess for debugging it is best practice to define your requires within the tasks that need them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue.
My gulp file has globally defined requires at the top for other tasks on the file.

```
//var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
//var foreach = require('gulp-foreach');
//var fileList = require('gulp-filelist');
//var gp_concat = require('gulp-concat');
//var gp_rename = require('gulp-rename');
//var gp_uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
//var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

//var watch = require('gulp-watch');
//var removeFiles = require('gulp-remove-files');
//var fs = require('fs');
```

While my task did not use them they still were initialized and therefore added to the debugging load time. What I will do is define them where ever I need them.